# A proof about the minimum of a mollified function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

How to prove the following claim?

Suppose $u$ is differentiable at $(x_0,t_0)\in R^n\times(0,\infty)$, $v$ is $C^1$. $u-v$ has a strict maximum at $(x_0,t_0)$.

Let $v^\epsilon=\eta_\epsilon*v$, $\eta_\epsilon$ denoting the usual mollifier in the $n+1$ variables $(x,t)$, then prove

$u-v^\epsilon$ has a maximum at some point $(x_\epsilon, t_\epsilon)$, with $(x_\epsilon, t_\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The space-time distinction is immaterial, as is the differentiability of $u$. The result is a special case of the following one:

**Claim**: Suppose $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, a function $u$ is continuous on $\Omega$, and $u$ has a strict maximum at a point $x_0$. Let $\{u_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions that converges to $u$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$. Then $u_n$ attains a maximum at a point $x_n$ such that $x_n\to x_0$ as $n\to\infty$.

*Proof*: For   sufficiently small $r>0$ we have 
$$u(x_0) > \sup_{|x-x_0|=r} u(x)$$
By uniform convergence, 
$$u_n(x_0) > \sup_{|x-x_0|=r} u_n(x)$$
holds for all sufficiently large $n$. Therefore $u$ attains a maximum somewhere in $\{x:|x-x_0|<r\}$. Since $r$ can be arbitrarily small, we conclude that the distance from $x_0$ to the set of  maximum points of   $ u_n$ tends to zero as $n\to\infty$. $\quad\Box$